# Mercurial HG library for Node.js for local repositories

Tags: node.js, mercurial, npm

I am looking for library written for Node.js
which I will be able to use to manage from the web application
my local repositories created in Mercurial HG.

Anyone implemented something like that?

Comment: If it's not on http://search.npmjs.org/ or https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules it probably doesn't exist (publicly)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never heard of such a library — it has not been announced on [our mailinglist](http://mercurial.markmail.org/search/?q=Node.js). The stable API for Mercurial is the [command line](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialApi), so I suggest just launching `hg` directly and parsing the output. It's designed to be easy to screen-scrape and you can further customize it by using [templates](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html).

Comment: If you use the command server you can avoid the hg startup overhead, however it involves a little bit more effort.

Comment: I thought about it, but as a final solution. Thanks for answers.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful (thought it's negative), then please remember to upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 7):

I've created a module available on npm called [node-hg](https://bitbucket.org/jacob4u2/node-hg) for precisely this reason.

It's a wrapper around the [Command Server](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CommandServer) that issues commands via `stdin` and parses output on `stdout`.

Here's an example of how it works:

```
var path = require("path");

var hg = require("hg");

// Clone into "../example-node-hg"
var destPath = path.resolve(path.join(process.cwd(), "..", "my-node-hg"));

hg.clone("http://bitbucket.org/jgable/node-hg", destPath, function(err, output) {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }

    output.forEach(function(line) {
        console.log(line.body);
    });

    // Add some files to the repo with fs.writeFile, omitted for brevity

    hg.add(destPath, ["someFile1.txt", "someFile2.txt"], function(err, output) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }

        output.forEach(function(line) {
            console.log(line.body);
        });

        var commitOpts = {
            "-m": "Doing the needful"
        };

        // Commit our new files
        hg.commit(destPath, commitOpts, function(err, output) {
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            }

            output.forEach(function(line) {
                console.log(line.body);
            });
        });
    });
});
```